# Add combo boxes to WordPress search form

Tags: wordpress, search, combobox

[image]

I would like to replace the default text box in the WordPress search form with four combo boxes as shown in the image above. I need to allow my users search for posts based on the values selected in the combo boxes.

Each combo box pulls the values of a custom field. e.g Property Type is supposed to check the values in the property_type custom field.

My headache is how to make the form look like the image above and also how to query the posts properly using combinations of those criteria. E.g. Searching for property type: Townhouse should give me all posts with "Townhouse" in the property_type custom field.

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that you will need to create a custom query , and to take the query string from the combined combo-boxes .

This query will also depend on how your search terms are ordered .

For example "Property Type" is a category ? a tag ?  taxonomy? A custom field  ??

This is a bit more complicated than a simple answer .

For example, if you want your search term to include "category" (assuming that "property type" is category  you can do this :

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    in <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_all=All Categories' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

or as a function:

```
function wp_combo_search_form($form) {
$form = '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="' . get_option('home') . '/" >
<div><label class="hidden" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
<input type="text" value="' . attribute_escape(apply_filters('the_search_query', get_search_query())) . '" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'.attribute_escape(__('Search')).'" />
<br />
'.wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all=All Categories&hide_empty=0&echo=0&selected='.intval($_GET['cat']).'').'
</div>
</form>';
return $form;
}

//uncomment following line for automatic filtering your theme
//add_filter('get_search_form', 'wp_combo_search_form');
```

Usage :

```
<?php echo wp_combo_search_form(''); ?>
```

But honestly - judging by the type of question and the "style" of it - I would suggest you search for a plugin to do that for you . [SEARCH HERE](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/)

**EDIT I**
there are still many ways and approaches to do so (jQuery, Json, direct query..) but :

now that you said that you need custom fields -

Since wp3.1 you can add meta_query to query_posts.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type', //typically "post"
    'meta_query' =>
        array(
            'key' => 'your_key',
            'value' => 'your_value',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE' //just an example
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'your_key_2"',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ), //value can be array
            'type' => 'numeric', //just an example
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN' //just an example
        )
)
query_posts( $args );
?>
```

first capture your variables in search.php like `$_GET['field name'];`

```
$p_type = $_GET['property_type'];
$p_city = $_GET['property_city'];
$n_bedrooms = $_GET['no_bedrooms'];
$n_bathrooms = $_GET['no_batrhooms'];
```

then pass it to query array

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
array(
            'key' => $p_type,
 'value' => $whatever,

        ),
        array(
            'key' => $p_city,
 'value' => $whatever,

        )
    ) // etc.etc...
 );
```

Now you only need to populate the dropdowns with the right values .

You can see an example (search fields - not dropdowns - but it is the same) here :

http://dev.matthewaprice.com/

and read how it´s done here :

http://matthewaprice.com/search-multiple-custom-fields-in-wordpress/

Read also here : http://www.wp1stop.com/wordpress-101-guide-search-multiple-custom-fields-in-wordpress-custom-field-search-custom-query-part-1/

Comment: Hi @Obmerk, thanks for your response, and sorry I wasn't more specific.
I want to search for posts based on the values in 4 custom fields. Each combo box is for a custom field. e.g Property Type is supposed to check the values in the property_type custom field.

My headache is how to make the form look like the image above and also how to query the posts properly using combinations of those criteria. E.g. Searching for property type: Townhouse should give me all posts with "Townhouse" in the property_type custom field.

Comment: thanks! This should handle my  requirements. I'll try it out and give you feedback.